# Snapping position to a grid that's size is <= 1

Tags: math, position, transformation, spatial

I'm creating a basic voxel editor that uses several different sizes of cubes.

The user has a slider the use to control the current cube size their editing with, then when adjusted changes the scale of the cube to-be-placed and the guide grid.

Now all I have left to do it to snap the placement cursor's position to the grid (just trying to get it to work right now, worrying about face direction calculations later). The grid sizes are <= 1 (0.2, 0.25, 0.33, 0.5, 1).

I can calculate the grid position using:

```
Vector3 currentPos = hit.point; /* where hit.point is the position in space of the cursor on the model*/
Vector3 GridLock = new Vector3(gridScale * Mathf.Round(currentPos.x / gridScale),
                               gridScale * Mathf.Round(currentPos.y / gridScale),
                               gridScale * Mathf.Round(currentPos.z / gridScale));
```

Which works fine for some grid positions (1, 0.33, 0.2) but for the other sizes (0.25, 0.5) the whole grid is offset by half a unit.

I'm sure this is just a basic math problem, but I'm having a tricky time figuring it out :(

Any help is appreciated!

**Example at size 1: (yellow cube is the grid clamped cursor)**

[image]

**Example at size 0.5: (yellow cube is offset to (I believe) the top and right)**

[image]

Comment: The code above is not the problem. May it be a rendering problem? I.e. you assumed the position as the box center in one place and as a corner in another?

Comment: @NicoSchertler The boxes positions are all at the center of each cube. It would make sense that maybe the grid positioning needs to it be at the corner, but then why are some grid scales fine?

Comment: That depends on how your boxes are aligned in the grid. So either use a corner-aligned grid or compensate for the alignment in your calculation. If you need assistance with that, you should add a figure that describes the box coordinates at different levels to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on the Unity Q&A site, and I got a helpful answer that was part of the problem. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1243447/snapping-to-grid-with-grid-size-of-1.html#answer-1243489

> Any ratio could be reduced to a 1 to X ratio
>
> - so 3 to 4 would be 1 to 1.3333 --> 1/3 off
> - and 3 to 5 would be 1 to 1.6666 --> 2/3 off
> - 4 to 5 would be 1 to 1.25 --> 1/4 off
> - 2 to 3 would be 1 to 1.5 --> 1/2 off
> - and the case above: 2 to 5 would be 1 to 2.5 --> 3/2 off
>
> That means all those cases don't fit together because every X cubes
>   there would be some cubes off
>
> So the problem why it doesn't work in your case is the combination of
>   using the center as well as odd ratios. If you have ratios that fit
>   together they will always be off by half a cube, But some which are
>   off every X cubes might fit nicely to the next larger grid every now
>   and then. This is generally called interference since you have two
>   different frequencies which overlap.

Basically since my grid was a combination of power of 2 and power of 3 values, not everything would fit together.

A neat try also learned from the answer is that is you want to take some number (e.g 1`, 2, 3`) and get power of 2 from them, you can use bitwise left shift to do so `1 << num` (e.g `1<<2 = 4`, `1<<3 = 8`).

The core issue I had though was using `Math.Round`. Even after switching to using cubes with a origen point in the bottom-left-left corner, there was still an offset. Changing it from using rounding to flooring (`Math.Floor`) fixed that offset.

This happened because as you crossed the half-way point in a grid tile, it would round up and you would get the position for the next grid.